# how to get parent component props from a raw html tag

Tags: vue.js

I get a component from NPM.

```
<collapsible :accordion="true">
  <collapsible-item>
    <p slot="header" class="bt f14"><span style="position: relative;top: 7px">test1</span></p>
    <p>body 1</p>
  </collapsible-item>
  <collapsible-item>
    <p slot="header" class="bt f14"><span style="position: relative;top: 7px">test2</span></p>
    <p>body 2</p>
  </collapsible-item>
</collapsible>
```

`<p slot="header" class="bt f14"><span style="position: relative;top: 7px">test2</span></p>'` has to be raw html tags. cause of I have try to define a component inside  `<collapsible-item >`. I want to get the 'isOpened' of the props of `<collapsible-item>`. so I change the style of the `<p slot="header" class="bt f14"><span style="position: relative;top: 7px">test2</span></p>'`.

Comment: Not really understanding what you need to do. Do you mean you need to change the component template to put your own attributes/properties?